# Displaying child taxonomy before parent

Tags: php, taxonomy

Hi can anyone please help me,

I want to display child taxonomy first before the parent.

Example: 
**Street Name** is the child,
**City Name** is the parent

to make it more formal, i want to display Street Name first before City Name.
like: Downtown street, Dubai

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption here is that within your data structure you have only two level hierarchy:

1. *Countries* are always top level parent terms (they never have their own parents),
2. *Streets* are first level children, and each street only has one parent and no children.

Do you need a list of all terms? In that case you could output all *Streets* by picking terms that do not have children, then loop through them to show their parents:

```
    <?php
    $terms = get_terms( [
       'taxonomy'   => 'your-taxonomy-name',
       'hide_empty' => false,
       'childless'  => true, // this will make sure we pick only terms that have no children, so no countries, only streets
    ] );
    ?> 

    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach( $terms as $street ) {
            $country = get_term( $street->parent, 'your-taxonomy-name' );

            if ( ! is_wp_error( $country ) ) {
                echo sprintf( '<li>%1$s, %2$s</li>', $street->name, $country->name );
            }
        }
        ?>
    <ul>
```